# vba Copy columns between tables checking index

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in a source document and I need to copy an entire column and paste it in another table in another Workbook but the cells of the column have to be pasted in terms of an **Index** (As the source and matching rows are not in the same order, and they cannot be)

I have created some code that copies the values using a vloockup function, but it shows two limitations:

1. **The source file is not allowed to have blank spaces**
2. **There is no way to copy also the format of the cell.**

Could you give me some guidance in the matter.

P.S: I am avoiding for loops in order to keep a good performance of the program , for that the use of tables, it is a bit more messy when writing code but it result in lower computation time.

Here is the solution that I am currently using:

```
Sub ss_action(path As String)

Dim formula As String

Dim prevFile As String
Dim temp As String

    path = Dir(path)
    prevFile = path + "!MyTable[[MyColumn1]:[MyColumnX]]"

    temp = "VLOOKUP([@MyColumn1]," & prevFile & ",3,0)"

    formula = "=IF(" & temp & "<> 0," & temp & ","""")"

    With Workbooks(taqrgetFile).Worksheets("TargetSheet")
        .Range("Table1[MyColumnX]").NumberFormat = "General"
        .Range("Table1[MyColumnX]").formula = formula
        .Range("Table1[MyColumnX]").Value = .Range("MyTable[MyColumnX]").Value
        .Activate
    End With

    MsgBox ("Import sucessfull")
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on point 1? What happens if the source file has blank cells?

Comment: If the Source file has blanks the formula does not work as the function does not recognize the full argument as a _range_, it stops parsing after the first blank instead.